What steps can I use to debug a GoogleGenerativeAI Error: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)
I am using Google's NodeJS SDK for GoogleGenerativeAI. I am making completion requests:
  const modelObj = this._googleAiClient.getGenerativeModel({ model: 'gemini-1.5-flash' });
  const result = await modelObj.generateContent(prompt);

I am using an API key with billing enabled:

However, I'm consistently getting:
GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent: [429 Too Many Requests] Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).

If I visit the quotas page: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/generativelanguage.googleapis.com/quotas
and search for gemini-1.5-flash, then the only limit I look remotely close to hitting is "Request limit per model per minute for a project in the free tier" -- however, as this is a Paid Plan, I wouldn't expect to be hitting that.
Does anyone know how I can debug this?

If you are going there, you have quotas at the project level (you might have to select your project first): https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?referrer=search&pageState=(%22allQuotasTable%22:(%22f%22:%22%255B%257B_22k_22_3A_22_22_2C_22t_22_3A10_2C_22v_22_3A_22_5C_22gemini_5C_22_22%257D%255D%22))
Here a screenshot of chat I have

Pick the right model (1.5 flash in your case) and identify what happens then. In summary (in paid plan):

4 millions token per minutes
2k request per minutes

If you are trying to only generate text and you are alone on the project is strange.
If you are multiple users, or if you are running a script to batch generate text, it could happen. Same thing, if you upload 3 or 4 long videos in parallel.

It seems like I'm definitely hitting the free-tier quota, but I can't see why. It's only me, and I'm running a small number of text completions concurrently
